# Framework7 - Routing to /login/ not working

Tags: html-framework-7

I am trying to render the following login.html page via framework7 router, but unfortunately i get HTTP 404 error

```
<div id="myapp">
     <div class = "views">
        <div class = "view view-main">
            <div class = "pages">
                <div data-name="login" class = "page stacked">
                   <div class = "page-content">
                        <div class = "login-screen-title">Login</div>
                        <div class = "list-block">
                                  <!-- Framework7 login form-->
                        </div>
                        <div class = "content-block">
                            <p><a href = "#" class = "button button-fill color-blue">Login</a></p>
                            <p><a href = "#" id="reset" class = "button button-fill color-gray">Reset</a></p>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
             </div>
                
             </div>
         </div>
          
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Path to your app js-->
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>
</div>
```

Additionally in my config framework7 file (my-app.js), i have got the following code:

```
var app = new Framework7({
  // App root element
  el: '#myapp',
  // App Name
  name: 'My App',
  // App id
  id: 'com.myapp.test',

  view:{
    stackPages:true,
  },
  // Enable swipe panel
  panel: {
    swipe: true,
  },
  // Add default routes
  routes: [
    {
      path:'/login/',
      //pageName:'login',
      url:'./login.html'
    },
  ],
});

var mainView = app.views.create('.view-main');
```

Any idea that could help me?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Please Specify Url in login button like this:**

```
<a href="/login/" class="button button-fill color-blue">Login</a>
```